# Asking Rails What Plugins it has Loaded, After Initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

At some point, this was valid:

```
Rails.plugins
```

But I cannot seem to make this work for me in Rails 2.3. What is the proper strategy to ask Rails about plugins that have been loaded, after its initialized them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what happened to `Rails.plugins`, but...

---

There's [a class that deals with plugin information](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Plugin.html#M000086).

There's also `script/plugin list`

---

If you're *really* curious about plugins and their information, take a look at

`$ $RUBYGEMS_DIR/rails-2.3.x/lib/commands/plugin.rb`

Comment: I've already looked through most of this, I was more curious if there was some missing piece I am not seeing.